# Long polling chat server

Tags: python, chat, long-polling

I need some help regarding some minor problems in this chat server I've written. As you can see, I am using a global variable 'chat' to store newly submitted messages. This is because I can't find a working pubsub module for MongoDB (or I just don't know how to use one). Because of this, when 2 people send message almost at the exact same time, only the newer message is being outputted. Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gevent
import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.event import Event
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

from flask import Flask, request, Response, render_template, jsonify

import time

from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

a = Event()
chat = {}

def logchat(data):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.chatlog
    db.bences.insert(data)

@app.route('/output')
def sse_request():
    a.wait()
    return jsonify(chat)

@app.route('/processchat', methods=['POST'])
def processchat():
    global chat
    ms = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    chat = {'name': request.form['chatname'], 'msg': request.form['chatmsg'], 'ts': ms}
    a.set(); a.clear()
    logchat(chat)
    return jsonify(success=True)

@app.route('/')
def page():
    return render_template('chat.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 80), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

What can you suggest for me to do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could drop global `chat` and use a queue: `chat = queue.get()` instead of `a.wait()` and `queue.put(chat)` instead of `a.set(); a.clear()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks! I'll try that and update my findings here. I was thinking of using queue but can't get my head wrapped around it

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian here's what happens: unlike using gevent's Event, a chat will only be delivered to a single user, not broadcasted to everybody. In case of 2 users, messages are distributed alternately. here's the code http://pastebin.com/edUcCNKn

Comment: queue works as expected but it won't help with the chat server (I should have payed attention to the title). To broadcast you need to keep track of clients and pending messages (substantial code changes).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian will do research about that. I already have the idea of creating a class spawning an instance so each greenlet will get its own queue, and will independently process the IO of messages. Again, I will update this when I reach some milestone. Thanks!

Comment: you could try to port [webchat example from django to flask](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/examples/webchat/chat/views.py)